# Как подружить Qt 5.6 и Visual Studio 2015 при сборке x64

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, x86-64

Написал проект на *VS Studio 2015* и использовал библиотеки *Qt* (инклуды и либы) для некоторых функций для парсинга. Сборка x32 работает без проблем.
Собираю сборку x64 (перед этим переподключив либы и инклуды из Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64), запускаю и падает ошибка:

> "Ошибка при запуске приложения 0xc000007b....".

При дебаге выходит:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDE7AAC5A0 (ntdll.dll) in READ_RESQML.exe: 0xC000007B: Программа "%hs" не предназначена для выполнения в Windows или содержит ошибку. Попробуйте установить программу еще раз с исходного установочного носителя либо обратитесь к системному администратору или поставщику программного обеспечения за поддержкой. Состояние ошибки 0x.

Comment: Значит ваша программа, либо одна из библиотек пытается из под 64 использовать/вызвать х86 код, что нельзя делать.